# How to add style using css for my first table row in for loop while using inner html

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, html-table, innerhtml

I just want to add style in my first `tr` on my inner HTML table how could I do this?

```
for (i = 0; i <= years_in_months; i++) {
    var powint1 = compound * (Math.pow(interest, i));
    powint1 = powint1.toFixed(0);


    var ointerest = (interest - 1)*100;
    ointerest = ointerest.toFixed(0); 

    tableHTML = tableHTML + "<tr><td>" + months2[i] + "</td><td> " + ointerest + "%"+"</td><td>"+ "$"+powint1 +"</td></tr>";
    document.getElementById("tdisplay").innerHTML = "<thead><tr><th>Month</th><th>Interest</th><th>Total Amount</th></tr></thead>"+ tableHTML;
}
```

Comment: Could you provided a larger portion of the script, so we can see what you are trying to achieve overall?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your css:

```
#tdisplay tr:nth-of-type(1) {
    /* Your Style*/
}
```

See [CSS :nth-of-type() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

You may want to move `document.getElementById("tdisplay").innerHTML = ...` outside the loop

Comment: yeah it work but what I want is on each loop. meaning every loop for example I have 3 loop on every loop I want to style the 1st tr

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer with my own, I just added class and put the value of i on it then do the CSS.

`tableHTML = tableHTML + "<tr class='table-"+[i]+"'><td>" + months2[i] + "</td><td> " + ointerest + "%"+"</td><td>"+ "$"+powint2 +"</td></tr>";`

CSS

`.table-0{background-color:yellow;}`

Comment: Maybe you could provide the code examples in code blocks rather than inline code formatting to show off your answer more concisely. Also you could provide a full JavaScript snippet.